# Implementation of forward-only caffe

Tags: android, ios, caffe

Is there any implementation of a forward-only [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org)? I am trying to use a trained caffe model on mobile devices like iPhone and android phones so I don't want to have a bunch of overheads like leveldb, hdf5, glog etc. Also, it only needs to run in CPU mode since the program will only run a forward pass to get the feature of the input image.

Currently I am trying to re-write the caffe source code to get a lighter caffe. I'm not sure if this work has been done by others. Also, I'm wondering if there is another way to use the trained caffe model on mobile devices (or other devices that come without all the dependencies required by caffe).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no forward-only caffe library. You could disable the use of many of the 3rd party libraries by uncommenting the appropriate lines in `Makefile.config`. But there are no flags in that file to comment out the use of glog library. Building in just the CPU mode too is made possible by editing the `Makefile.config` appropriately.

There are works being done by some to port the caffe to mobile devices. One such project can be found [here](https://github.com/sh1r0/caffe-android-lib).

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly why I am writing this project: https://github.com/solrex/caffe-mobile .

I have finished the iOS part, with a demo iOS app. I'm working on the Android part. The JNI interface will take me some time.